# Failed assertion: line 190 pos 15: 'items!= null': is not true

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, navigation

I am trying to build a Bottom Curved navigation bar in the flutter, I have tried many examples but nothing worked for me. Even I used the same example as it is on their official website but nothing happened.
I am trying to build a Bottom Curved navigation bar in the flutter, I have tried many examples but nothing worked for me. Even I used the same example as it is on their official website but nothing happened.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: BottomNavBar()));

class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomNavBarState createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  int _page = 0;
  GlobalKey _bottomNavigationKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
          key: _bottomNavigationKey,
          index: 0,
          height: 50.0,
          items: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.add, size: 30),
            Icon(Icons.list, size: 30),
            Icon(Icons.compare_arrows, size: 30),
            Icon(Icons.call_split, size: 30),
            Icon(Icons.perm_identity, size: 30),
          ],
          color: Colors.white,
          buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
          animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _page = index;
            });
          },
        ),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(_page.toString(), textScaleFactor: 10.0),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Go To Page of index 1'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    final CurvedNavigationBarState navBarState =
                        _bottomNavigationKey.currentState;
                    navBarState.setPage(1);
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: For me everything working fine.
I tried it on iOS virtual device with Flutter 1.9.1+hotfix.6 • channel stable.
What configuration do you have?

Comment: assert(items != null),
       assert(items.length >= 2),
        assert(
        items.every((BottomNavigationBarItem item) => item.title != null) == true,
        'Every item must have a non-null title',

Comment: this is the exception

Comment: Which version of the library do you use? 
There is no `assert(items.length >= 2)` in library version 0.3.1, so try to update your libraries with `flutter pub get` and let me know what's the file where error occurs.

Comment: I am using ^0.3.1

Comment: Thanks for your time buddy. It's done

Answer (score 0):

I've used the same example from the current documentation of the [curved_navigation_bar plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar/example) and it works fine. I am using the version 1.0.1 and here is the output:

[image]